# Show that this series go to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that $\sum _{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2}$ goes to $0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. It seems obvious, but I must have it the formal way.

Comment: It is neither obvious nor true.  Note that the sum is greater than $1$.

Comment: @Callus It is $\sum_{k = 1}^n 1/k^2$ that goes to $\pi^2/6$. That's not what is in question here.

Comment: Is there a typo? Since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^2} = n\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This is a good trap !

Comment: yeah, there is $1/n^2$, not $k$

Comment: @Arthur Ah! My mistake.  Will leave it here in case others misread as well ( guessing the two upvotes my comment has received show I'm not the only one )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have immediately the desired result by

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n^2}=\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$

Comment: The first equality is by definition of multiplication, by the way: You have $n$ terms, all equal to $1/n^2$. Their sum is therefore $n \cdot 1/n^2 = n/n^2$.